# kendo grid row double click event not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

### kendo grid row double click event not working

Hi ,
 I am working on a web application with kendo grid and i've bind doubleclick event to the grid.But when the user click in a particular cell the double click event not firing.I think those cells having inner templates like "div"(click event works fine.The issue is only in double click).Any help?

Comment: It would help if we could see some code or a jsfiddle/plunkr.

Comment: Sure.this event will fire when i click the element dynamically using jquery but not in manual click.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$("#grid").on("dblclick", "tr.k-state-selected", function () {
    alert("Double click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have the dbl click event on the tr row element. That way you can access your dataItem object in the kendo grid if needed. In your kendogrid databound event, add this code:

```
if ($("#your-grid").find("tbody").children().length <= 0) {
        $.each($("#your-grid").find("tbody").find("tr"), function () {
                $(this).addClass("row-dbl-click");
        });
    }
```

Now you need to handle the dbl click event:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", ".row-dbl-click", function (e) { //do stuff });
```

I havent tested it but it should work. Good luck.

Comment: In my cause html double click will work but some cells having edit templates.Because of that first of all it goes to edit function of kendo grid and stops there.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for Double click event :

```
$('#grid table tr').live('dblclick', function () {
```

alert(' grid dbl clicked');
});